# Do I need to write unit tests for methods of services without logic?

Tags: unit-testing

Do I need test service methods like this?

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Charge saveAndFlush(Charge charge) {
    return chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(charge);
}
```

In principle, there is nothing to test. Therefore, the question arose - to write a test anyway, because in the future it is possible that someone will add logic here. Or let him write the one who will add logic (if at all).

Comment: If there's nothing to test or the code is trivial such as in simple getters and setters then I'd not write any tests. Writing a test now in case there might be logic added doesn't feel like it makes much sense because you don't know that that logic is going to be. However, depending on your needs, you might still have to test that method to make sure the call `chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(charge)` succeeds and returns what you need - as I said that would depend on your needs, i.e. do you need to verify that `chargesRepository` is set or that the charge can be saved (e.g. no missing data)?

Comment: Well, for these purposes, I can write a test suite for testing all repository methods

Comment: The general problem of more practical examples is that the requirements and resources differ from team to team, product to product etc. Writing and maintaining tests doesn't come for free so business decisions will probably influence what is tested and how - and explaining those for a more complex example might be a little too much.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you focus your unit tests on code that returns a value by performing some computation or processing.
You could unit test a method that does not return any value to ensure it's going through without running exceptions while executing all the possible paths.
In the case above I believe you should not write a test for it. There's really no logic in that method and you'd be unit testing the spring framework. There's no need for that as the spring framework already has plenty of unit tests.
Do notice unit tests are supposed to run fast and must work standalone, that is, a unit test cannot depend on a database or network connection. So that's another reason not to unit test it as you would depend on a database to verify the code worked.

Answer (score 2):

> there is nothing to test

Well, there is. Because doing no tests can not distinguish between the correct implementation and the following faulty "implementations":

```
{
   return null;
}

{
   return chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(null);
}

{
   return chargesRepository.saveAndFlush(new Charge());
}

{
   return chargesRepository.someOtherMethod(charge);
}
```

But you are right to think there is *very little* to test. Assuming the class of `chargesRepository` is already properly tested, you only need one or two unit tests to show that the method correctly delegates to the `chargesRepository`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer to a similar question:

Kent Beck's rule of thumb:

Test everything that could possibly break.
Of course, that is subjective to some extent. To me, trivial getters/setters and one-liners like yours above usually aren't worth it. But then again, I spend most of my time writing unit tests for legacy code, only dreaming about a nice greenfield TDD project... On such projects, the rules are different. With legacy code, the main aim is to cover as much ground with as little effort as possible, so unit tests tend to be higher level and more complex, more like integration tests if one is pedantic about terminology. And when you are struggling to get overall code coverage up from 0%, or just managed to bump it over 25%, unit testing getters and setters is the least of your worries.

OTOH in a greenfield TDD project, it may be more matter-of-fact to write tests even for such methods. Especially as you have already written the test before you get the chance of starting to wonder "is this one line worth a dedicated test?". And at least these tests are trivial to write and fast to run, so it's not a big deal either way.

Comment: *which* similar question? Copying answers without attribution is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

The key reason for this method to exist is the transactional annotation and the side effect on the charges repository. That's also the most likely/only thing to not work as expected. That's something you find out with an integration test. Unit testing this is completely pointless because you'd mock the storage and ignore the annotations. So, you are basically unit testing that a random call on a mock works. Which, surprisingly, tends to mostly work as you'd hope.

So, make sure you cover all relevant repository methods with only a few good integration/scenario tests (i.e. don't write one per method but combine them into realistic scenarios). Focus unit tests on things with algorithmic complexity that have more than 1 line of code or any kind of branches. That way you can mock your DAO class when unit testing your service classes with actual business logic may have real bugs because you already know the DAOs have the desired side effects from integration testing.

Answer (score 1):

why do you write tests at all? to have easier life. don't be fanatic, be pragmatic.

**what will be the cost?**

time spent on writing, time spent on each execution by every single developer forever, more code, time spent on maintenance, code duplication (i hope you have integration tests for your db)

**what will be the value?**

- checking if method A directly delegates to B? in such case maybe you don't need A at all
- checking if transaction is pending or if the db operations are correct? you'll need integration tests for that
- checking if nothing else is done in the method? you will need mutation tests for that

so it's really hard to see real value in this test. additionally: do you expect this code to change often? will it be really bad if it fails (10 mins of fixing / call in the night / 1M $ loss / plane crashes)? if the answers are 'no' then the cost is much bigger than value

**but...**

- if this is widely used method in your app and other devs often by misunderstanding remove `@Transactional`? add test! check by reflection if the annotation is present
- if it's very critical method? do mutation testing, check if the delegation is done, check if parameter is not changed
- if you expect this method will change often and cause a lot of troubles? add test that checks the basic properties are preserved (transactional and delegation)

so just keep your life as easy as possible. depending on your context it will be easier with or without the test

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd skip writing a test for this service method for now. You'll need to write tests for your MVC part anyway. Checking that the endpoint:

- Returns JSON/XML/whatever
- Accepts and parses HTTP params
- Doesn't access lazy fields
- Propagates the logic to the right service and initiates ORM sessions and transactions

The endpoint will invoke this service and will test it implicitly.

Later when you add more logic to this service - you can add service-layer tests as well (writing a lot of MVC tests is harder and slower). I wouldn't write those as *unit* tests though (see articles below).

> P.S where I can read about what exactly and how to test? ... I still have not found practical examples of how to test and what is more difficult to test than hello world

Hope these will help:

- [Building Test Pyramid to optimize automated testing](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html)
- [Anemic architecture - enemy of testing](http://qala.io/blog/anaemic-architecture-enemy-of-testing.html)