# How to unit test functions that its input doesn't change functions behaviour at all?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm having trouble sometimes while thinking about unit testing. Lets look at this scenario:

```
@POST
    @Path("/search")
    public Response searchSelections(SearchRequestDto searchRequestDto,
        @BeanParam ScrollableDto scrollableDto) {
        Scrollable scrollable = Scrollable.getScrollable(scrollableDto);
        Page<SelectionDto> selectionDtos =
            selectionService.search(searchRequestDto, scrollable);
        return Response.ok(selectionDtos).build();
    }
```

So in this Controller unit test (not talking about integration), from business perspective I expect those:

1. If searchRequestDto is null, no filter is applied, I expect all
   entities.
2. If scrollableDto is null, no pagination is applied, I
   expect all entities.
3. If nothing is found whether searchRequest,
   scrollable is null or not, if nothing is found in database, I expect
   page object with empty list with HTTP.OK.

So how can I unit test here? All of the numbers I have defined above is under responsibility of another classes. So all I can do is mocking of them without any check in my searchSelections() function which i test here. For example;

If scrollableDto is null (which is number 2 above):

- First line of my function above -> I don't care because it is responsibility of Scrollable.getScrollable function which is already unit tested.
- Second line of my function above -> Response is scrollable from the above. So this scrollable is parameter of selectionService.search, also I don't care this too because it is already unit tested. So scrollableDto null or not null effects my previous line which is just mocking, it doesn't effect my current functions state.
- Last line of my function above -> I should return selectionDtos from previous mock. Now my number 2 unit test scenario which is scrollableDto = null have no meaning for me since it is mocked, it's result is mocked.

Same for my other unit test scenarios. How should I think when my parameters doesn't change the state of my function under the test, it just effects another already unit tested functions state, which I mock?

(I don't want verify method calls which doesn't have any valuable output for me, also it always increases our testing cost which should always be updated if function is refactored but its output is same. While nothing is changed we need to update our tests too which takes time if function call/ parameters verified, except some cases like database call etc.)

Answer (score 0):

So why do you insist on unit-testing this method? You only need 1 or 2 high-level (you call them Integration) tests that check that it all works together from Controller to DB.

Tests impose additional maintenance costs, so if you can omit them (and in this case you can) - that's great.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705629/do-i-need-to-write-unit-tests-for-methods-of-services-without-logic/53705847#53705847

Comment: You can find my answer there as well

Answer (score 0):

You have two data transformations

```
Scrollable scrollable = Scrollable.getScrollable(scrollableDto);
```

and

```
return Response.ok(selectionDtos).build();
```

And you have one dependency:

```
Page<SelectionDto> selectionDtos = selectionService.search(searchRequestDto, scrollable);
```

- So the arrange phase should stub the dependency in a way that the result of `Scrollable.getScrollable(scrollableDto)` returns a page of selection.
- The act phase should call `searchSelections` with the constrains in scenario 2
- The assert phase should assert that the response contains exactly the page of selection you stubbed in the arrange phase

This test is probably faster than an integration test. Yet if you plan to test this method integratively anyway you could also skip this test.